# Can I check with oauth2 if the user has a verified email on the discord account?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, oauth-2.0, discord.js

Can I check with oauth2 if the user has a verified email or telephone on the discord account?

I need this because I want to create a verification (ticket bot)
Please do not reply in a way that "you have this option in the server settings".

Information:
discord.js v14
javascript
node.js

I tried to search on the internet (I'm Polish so it's hard to search using the translator).

Comment: Check this: https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/user#user-object. You could (on your server) send a request to `"https://discord.com/api/users/{user.id}"`, for example.
Use the `verified` field in the response to know if a user's **email** is verified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an email scope for Discord's OAuth2 but not a phone number scope. [Here's the documentation](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/oauth2#shared-resources-oauth2-scopes).

If the user has a verified email, that will be sent to your application during the callback. If the email field isn't there, you can assume the user doesn't have a verified email.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there is a way to know if the user has a verified phone number or email via oAuth.

That being said, there is a setting to only allow people in the server that have a verified phone number/email.

Answer (score 0):

Unlucky, there is no option to verify that via OAuth2, you have to verify provider by yourself, and decide if you trust it or not. Discord is one of the providers. Discord is one of the providers that do not require confirmation of the e-mail address by the user.